# How did John Doe get past the dogs?

Tags: plot-explanation, se7en

How did John Doe get past the dogs that you see in a scene in *Se7en* where Det. Somerset has dinner at the Mills' or warned Tracy that John Doe wanted to harm/kill her?

Answer (score 4):

## Probably because they were locked up

Firstly, the dogs aren't **guard dogs**, they are house pets and don't attack strangers automatically and they would have no way of knowing that John Doe was there to kill Tracey.

However, as I said, what we do **know** is that the dogs don't generally have the run of the Mills' apartment.

They're kept shut into a separate room as we see when Somerset comes for dinner and Mills plays with them.

[image]